# Error using akka remoting with artery over docker instances

Tags: java, docker, akka, akka-remoting

First of all, sorry for my english. Google translate helps me a lot, haha.

My problem is this:

I have two example projects developed with `akka` and `java`: example-remote-client.jar and example-remote-server.jar

I'm using artery serialization, and and i'm trying to send messages from client to server via akka-remoting.

The client actor that does that is:

```
public class ClientActor extends AbstractActor {

    public static Props props() {
        return Props.create(ClientActor.class);

    }

    public ClientActor() {
        ActorSelection selection = getContext().system().actorSelection("akka://server@localhost:5001/user/server-process");
        selection.tell(new MessageRequest(), getSelf());
    }

    public Receive createReceive() {
        return receiveBuilder().match(MessageResponse.class, msg -> {
            System.out.println(msg.getMessage());
        }).build();
    }
}
```

My client configuration:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"

  actor {
    provider = remote
    allow-java-serialization = off


    serializers {
      java = "akka.serialization.JavaSerializer"
      myown = "serializers.ExampleByteBufSerializer"
    }

    serialization-bindings {
      "java.lang.String" = myown
      "protocol.MessageRequest" = myown
      "protocol.MessageResponse" = myown
      "java.lang.Boolean" = myown
    }

  }

  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      canonical.hostname = "192.168.0.250"     # external (logical) hostname
      canonical.port = 5000                   # external (logical) port

      bind.hostname = "localhost" # internal (bind) hostname
      bind.port = 10000              # internal (bind) port
    }
  }
}
```

The server actor is very dummy, i dont think it is necessary to paste it here. But its configuration is:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "DEBUG"

  actor {
    provider = remote
    allow-java-serialization = off


    serializers {
      java = "akka.serialization.JavaSerializer"
      myown = "serializers.ExampleByteBufSerializer"
    }

    serialization-bindings {
      "java.lang.String" = myown
      "protocol.MessageRequest" = myown
      "protocol.MessageResponse" = myown
      "java.lang.Boolean" = myown
    }

  }

  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      canonical.hostname = "192.168.0.250"     # external (logical) hostname
      canonical.port = 5001                   # external (logical) port

      bind.hostname = "localhost" # internal (bind) hostname
      bind.port = 10001              # internal (bind) port
    }
  }
}
```

Both jar are deployed over docker instances running over the same "192.168.0.250 machine", as seen below:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
d2970bd20371        openjdk:alpine             "sh"                     34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:5001->10001/tcp                          ex-remoting-server
36a67fea8590        openjdk:alpine             "sh"                     34 minutes ago      Up 34 minutes       0.0.0.0:5000->10000/tcp                          ex-remoting-client
```

The server starts ok, with the following log:

```
[DEBUG] [07/04/2017 13:46:18.473] [main] [EventStream(akka://server)] logger log1-Logging$DefaultLogger started
[DEBUG] [07/04/2017 13:46:18.473] [main] [EventStream(akka://server)] Default Loggers started
[DEBUG] [07/04/2017 13:46:18.495] [main] [akka.serialization.Serialization(akka://server)] Replacing JavaSerializer with DisabledJavaSerializer, due to `akka.actor.allow-java-serialization = off`.
[INFO] [07/04/2017 13:46:18.628] [main] [akka.remote.artery.ArteryTransport(akka://server)] Started embedded media driver in directory [/dev/shm/aeron-root-server-efd42dec-452d-406c-8d1d-807e0d8ff7fc]
[INFO] [07/04/2017 13:46:18.693] [main] [akka.remote.artery.ArteryTransport(akka://server)] Remoting started; listening on address: [akka://server@192.168.0.250:5001] with UID [-2663186266051514585]
```

But when i try to start client, i get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [07/04/2017 14:09:05.250] [client-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-10] [akka://server@192.168.0.250:5001/] swallowing exception during message send
io.aeron.exceptions.RegistrationException: Insufficient usable storage for new log of length=50332096 in /dev/shm (shm)
    at io.aeron.ClientConductor.onError(ClientConductor.java:285)
    at io.aeron.DriverListenerAdapter.onMessage(DriverListenerAdapter.java:79)
    at org.agrona.concurrent.broadcast.CopyBroadcastReceiver.receive(CopyBroadcastReceiver.java:100)
    at io.aeron.DriverListenerAdapter.pollMessage(DriverListenerAdapter.java:59)
    at io.aeron.ClientConductor.doWork(ClientConductor.java:422)
    at io.aeron.ClientConductor.awaitResponse(ClientConductor.java:447)
    at io.aeron.ClientConductor.addPublication(ClientConductor.java:177)
    at io.aeron.Aeron.addPublication(Aeron.java:165)
    at akka.remote.artery.AeronSink$$anon$1.<init>(AeronSink.scala:103)
    at akka.remote.artery.AeronSink.createLogicAndMaterializedValue(AeronSink.scala:100)
    at akka.stream.impl.GraphStageIsland.materializeAtomic(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:627)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:458)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:420)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:415)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:439)
    at akka.remote.artery.Association.akka$remote$artery$Association$$runOutboundOrdinaryMessagesStream(Association.scala:570)
    at akka.remote.artery.Association.runOutboundStreams(Association.scala:510)
    at akka.remote.artery.Association.associate(Association.scala:502)
    at akka.remote.artery.AssociationRegistry.association(Association.scala:763)
    at akka.remote.artery.ArteryTransport.association(ArteryTransport.scala:932)
    at akka.remote.artery.ArteryTransport.send(ArteryTransport.scala:918)
    at akka.remote.RemoteActorRef.$bang(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:563)
    at akka.actor.ActorRef.tell(ActorRef.scala:124)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$.rec$1(ActorSelection.scala:250)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection$.deliverSelection(ActorSelection.scala:254)
    at akka.actor.ActorSelection.tell(ActorSelection.scala:45)
    at actors.ClientActor.<init>(ClientActor.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at akka.util.Reflect$.instantiate(Reflect.scala:44)
    at akka.actor.NoArgsReflectConstructor.produce(IndirectActorProducer.scala:105)
    at akka.actor.Props.newActor(Props.scala:213)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:563)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:589)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:484)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I also try to send message with these "ActorSelection paths":

> "akka://server@192.168.0.250:5001/user/server-process"
>   "akka://server@localhost:5001/user/server-process"
>   "akka://server@192.168.0.250:10001/user/server-process"
>   "akka://server@localhost:10001/user/server-process"

but the error still appears.

It is important to clarify, also, that the actor path of the server actor is:

> akka://server/user/server-process

What is missing? I'm using akka 2.5.3 version...

Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure how Akka canonical vs bind addressing works. But my guess is that the `bind.hostname` is the actual IP or resolved IP by the hostname that it will listen on. In this case, `localhost` translates to `127.0.0.1`, which means the container will only accept connections on `127.0.0.1`.

Try setting the `bind.hostname` to `0.0.0.0`. This will allow connections from IP addresses outside the container (from host through port 5001).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the size of your `/dev/shm` volume to be larger. In a docker-compose file, you can simply add this option: `shm_size: 500M`. This volume is a shared memory space that aeron uses to buffer messages.